# Azure VM Windows Server 2016 Keyboard Japanese Input English

Tags: windows, server, keyboard, cjk

I've deployed an Azure VM Windows Server 2016.
Entering special characters like + (Shift ;　れ Key) in Search works fine.
However when I open an application like Notepad and hit Shift ;　れ Key
it returns :
So for whatever reason the Keyboard changes when opening an application.

How can I set my Keyboard input to English on the Japanese Keyboard?

[key1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5jdk.jpg)[key2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynrFE.jpg)[key3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl9Gn.jpg)[key4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSa3i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be fixed by setting the value of
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000411
to kbd106.dll from KBDJPN.DLL